# Getting null or empty error even though i controlled it

Tags: string, kotlin, if-statement, null

Though I controlled it with an if statement I'm getting ''Given string empty or null'' error and my app is closing.

```
fun kayitOl ( view : View) {


    val email =findViewById<EditText>(R.id.emailText).text
    val password  = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passwordText).text

        if (email != null && password != null ) {
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.toString(), password.toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val intent = Intent(this, haber_akisi::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()

                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Lütfen E-mail ve Password alanlarını doldurunuz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }



}
```

Comment: In what row you have exception?

Comment: Please don't answer your question by editing it, if you solved the problem yourself you can write your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check just for `null`, but not for empty string `""`

You can change your checking with `email.isEmpty()` or better `email.isBlank()` for checking strings like `" "`

Comment: i changed like  ´if ( email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty() )´ but nothing changed

Comment: I'm repeating question above. In what row do you have exception? The stacktrace wiil help us to help you.
May be you have exception before your chekings, it's not clear form question.

Comment: Ah sorry ı cant find that İ'm new to coding and İ'm looking the logcat in AndroidStudio but it does not show what row i have